# Format a string using a string pattern

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, dom-events, visual-studio-2005

I have a displayFormat pattern  "$###,###,###;-$###,###,###;#" (it can be different too) and I want to reformat the value in the AspxTextbox after deleting the ',' on `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events by calling the following JavaScript function :

```
function TextBoxFormat(ctrl, e, displayFormat, charactersToRemove) {
var value = ctrl.GetValue();
var i;

if (value != null && charactersToRemove != null) {
    for (i = 0; i < charactersToRemove.length; i++)
        value = value.replace(charactersToRemove[i], '');

    ctrl.SetValue(ASPxFormatter.Format('{0:' + displayFormat + '}', 
         parseInt(value)));
}
```

I have tried to use ASPxFormatter but it is an internal class that is not indented to be used in a user project using `String.Format('{0:' + displayFormat + '}', parseInt(value)));` didn't work either, it threw an exception since `String.format` doesn't accept this format of pattern.
Can you please provide a way to reformat my string to any pattern I want not only the one I illustrated?
I highly appreciate your support....

Comment: You could try googling for inputmasks ? Which is apparently what you are trying to achieve if I read your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The [MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) in the ajax control toolkit looks very much like what you want to do. If you don't want to use the pre-built controls, you can get the javascript source in one of the download packages.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer,it seems a good idea, I couldn't get the javascript source code, would you provide it ot me ?

Comment: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/43475 this page gives the download options. the javascript source should be available in one of those- probably AjaxControlToolkit.Source.zip ?

Comment: That is too much complicated for a simple task, it should be something in JavaScript to get the value and reformat it according to the given pattern

Answer (score 0):

Here is the format function...

```js
String.format = function() {
  var s = arguments[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {       
    var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");             
    s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
  }

  return s;
}
```